# Where does my console program's text file go when it is run from a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, process

I need to run a console application for which I do not have any source code (I only have the binaries) from my WCF REST web service. Once my service is up and running (localhost, debug), I enter the following code :

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = strCommand;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommandParameters;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

My **.exe** file is found but nothing happens. I put a breakpoint after this code and it stops there so the code is executed. Whatever happens regarding the command parameters, the console application is supposed to produce at least a **log.txt** file in its directory, but it does not. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** It *was* working...the only difference is the **log.txt** file was generated in the debug directory of the running web application instead of the directory of the console application. So the relative path of the output file is relative to the server web application.

Answer (score 0):

I´d guess you are hosting the WCF Service in IIS and the console application is started using the AppPool Credentials not having enough privileges. You may try to use the [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the Service/ConsoleApp and check for access denied messages

Comment: It looks like a nice tool, thanks ! The problem is my applicatiosn did not even show up in the log... No denied accesses either. If I allow the process to show the window I can see it pop up very shortly so it really looks like some access has been denied. Where/how can I handle this ?

Comment: See if you have write access in the log directory. And the userid you use to write has elevated previlages. Just basic but we may miss some time.

Comment: check that the app pool identity account has access as well.